# Using NMOSFET for driving negative voltage

Tags: nmos, negative-voltage

I want to use NMOSFEts for driving negative voltage. Is it possible to use it?

[image]

Comment: Yes, but not like that. You need the gate to switch between -24V and about -15V, not 0V and 5V.

Comment: that 5 volts is only for the pull-up resistor. I want the mosfet drives "-24" when it gets the "PS-C3" signal from MICRO.

Comment: Doing the Pspice simulation using the same circuit I see that it works.